# Splitting a vector into groups of a predefined size

Tags: matlab, vector, grouping, vectorization, matrix-indexing

I'm looking for a way to split an input vector into groups of a predefined size, with the last group being smaller if there is a remainder. I prefer the output as a cell, but I don't mind if it's any other class as long as it provides access to the subgroups using subsequent indexing.

Below are examples of the expected behavior:

```matlab
% Even split
v = 1:6;
grpSz = 2;
% OUT: {[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]}

% Remainder
v = 1:5;
grpSz = 3;
% OUT: {[1,2,3], [4,5]}

% Single group
v = 1:5;
grpSz = 6;
% OUT: {[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Below are a couple of useful quantities:

- Number of groups in the output: `nG = ceil(numel(v)/grpSz)`
- Number of elements in the last group: `r = mod(numel(v), grpSz)`

---

At the moment I'm using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```matlab
function out = evenSplitter(v, grpSz)
nV = numel(v);
nG = ceil(nV/grpSz);
r = mod(nV, grpSz);
out = mat2cell(v, 1, [repmat(grpSz, 1, nG-1), ~r*grpSz+r]);
```

...which works, but looks a bit clunky. Would anybody suggest a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution using [`splitapply`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html):

```
v     = 1:5;                                           % input array
grpSz = 2;                                             % maximal group size
out   = splitapply(@(x){x},v,ceil((1:numel(v))/grpSz)) % split v
```

This method works for all the given examples.

`splitapply` split data into groups and apply function. The anonymous function `@(x){x}` simply put each element of a group into a cell. And `ceil((1:numel(v))/grpSz)` create an array that indicate which elements are associated with which groups.

For example, if `v = 1:5` and `grpSz = 2`, `ceil((1:numel(v))/grpSz)` produce the following array `[1 1 2 2 3]`.

Answer (score 3):

This may be faster than `accumarray` for large inputs:

```
out = arrayfun(@(k) v(k:min(k+grpSz-1, end)), 1:grpSz:numel(v), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing it with `arrayfun` and `UniformOutput`, but couldn't quite piece it together... Good job!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, inspired by (and largely equivalent to) [obchardon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4363864/obchardon) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65321000/3372061):

```matlab
function out = evenSplitter(v, grpSz)
idx = ceil((1:numel(v))/grpSz);                       % Group ID of each element
out = accumarray( idx.', v, [idx(end) 1], @(x){x} );  % idx(end) == nG
```

This uses [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) which might be faster than [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html).